# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.ANRAppManager.dumpMessageHistory

Tags: android, exception, crash, crash-reports

My Android App reported some crash report:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.ANRAppManager.dumpMessageHistory
at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpMessageHistory(ActivityThread.java:1177)
at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:609)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

A lot of android device reported the same crash:

```
Android|Android=>3
android|Coolpad=>1
Android|Lenovo=>1
Android|VIVO=>2
apsl|Lenovo=>1
apsl|Samsung=>2
ARES|AE912=>3
Coolpad|Coolpad=>2
COWW|C920=>5
GoDonie|GoDonie F7=>1
HESM|HSEM TD777=>2
HMI|H2=>1
huawei|huawei=>2
intki|intki_E86=>3
ioco|i9100 X6=>1
Lenovo|Lenovo A820T=>1
MEEG|MEEG_101M=>2
NEWLAND|N003=>2
SAST|SAST YC500=>1
```

But I didn't find "dumpMessageHistory" in my code, please help, thanks!!

Comment: How to resolve this issue,  do you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The class `android.app.ANRAppManager` can not be found in Android Application Framework (`/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app`). Probably it is a vendor supplied class for MTK chips. Whenever there is an ANR raised, `ANRAppManager.dumpMessageHistory` would be invoked.

The best advice would be to keep track of all cases of ANR that takes place in your app and try to fix it.